# Hadoop - textouputformat.separator use ctrlA ( ^A )

Tags: hadoop, separator, control-characters

I'm trying to use ^A as the separator between Key and Value in my reduce output files.
I found that the config setting "mapred.textoutputformat.separator" is what I want and this correctly switches the separator to ",":

```
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ",");
```

But it can't handle the ^A character:

```
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "\u0001");
```

throws this error:

`ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user (auth:SIMPLE) cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 68; columnNumber: 94; Character reference "&#`

I found this ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7542 and see they tried to fix this but reverted the patch due to XML1.1 concerns.

SO I'm wondering if anyone has had success setting the separator to ^A (seems pretty common), using an easy work around. Or if I should just settle and use tab separator.

Thanks!

I'm running Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u5 on CentOS 6.2

Comment: Upvote, this is a valid question, must be encouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking around it looks like there are maybe three options that i've found for solving this problem:

- [Character reference “&#1” is an invalid XML character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308480/character-reference-1-is-an-invalid-xml-character) - similar SO question
- [Unicode characters/Ctrl G or Ctrl A as TextOutputFormat (Hadoop) delimiter](http://hadoopified.wordpress.com/2011/06/24/unicode-charactersctrl-g-or-ctrl-a-as-textoutputformat-hadoop-delimiter/)

The possible solutions as detailed in the link above are:

1. You can Base64 encode the separator character. You then need to create a custom TextOutputFormat that overrides the getRecordWriter method and decodes the Base64 encoded separator.
2. Create a custom TextOutputFormat again, except change the default separator character from a tab.
3. Provide the delimiter through an XML resource file. You can specify a custom resource file using the addResource() method of the jobs Configuration.

Comment: Thanks BN. #3 sounds like the cleanest approach. I'll give that a shot.